# How would I print the variable of i in a tkinter box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a random prize winner generator as a project and have never used any GUI tools.

```
import random
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import *
import time

# Open the file and select a random winner
names = open('names.txt').read().splitlines()
winner = random.choice(names)

#create the window and basic setup
window = Tk()
window.title("Bergstrom Prize Winner Generator")
window.geometry('500x500')

#action to be performed when button clicked
def clicked():
    for x in range(1,3):
        for i in names:
            print(random.choice(names))
            time.sleep(0.25)

    print("and the winner is.....", winner, "!!!!")

btn1 = Button(window, text="Pick A Winner!", command=clicked)
btn1.grid(column=3, row=3)

window.mainloop()
```

I want to display the value for `i` in the tkinter window so it flashes the names up, and then finally shows the name of the winner. I am absolutely stuck. Would anyone be able to advise please?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Label(master, text = i)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will list all the names in the names.txt file and then print the winner. You can increase the time delay.

**Code:**

```
import random
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import *
import time

# Open the file and select a random winner
names = open('names.txt').read().splitlines()
winner = random.choice(names)

#create the window and basic setup
window = Tk()
window.title("Bergstrom Prize Winner Generator")
window.geometry('500x500')

#action to be performed when button clicked
def clicked():
    for ind, name in enumerate(names):
        # print names in the tkinter window
        names_label = Label(window)
        names_label.grid(row=int(ind)+1, column=0)
        names_label.config(text=name)
    time.sleep(0.25)
    names_label.config(text="and the winner is....." + winner + "!!!!")

btn1 = Button(window, text="Pick A Winner!", command=clicked)
btn1.grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for the reply. This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it is a step towards it. What I am after is everytime the loop iterates, to print the i value so the name flashes up rather than a list of all the names